# Why does The Hibernate adds a child to it's parent children list when the association attribute of the child is set?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a parent entity:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "\"User\"") @XmlRootElement
public class User extends BaseEntity implements Serializable{
    .
    .
    .
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH}, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<AuthenticationToken> authenticationTokens;

    .
    .
    .
}
```

And a child entity:

```
@Entity @XmlRootElement
public class AuthenticationToken extends BaseEntity implements Serializable{
    .
    .
    .

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Then i add a helper method to the `user`

```
public User addAuthenticationToken( final AuthenticationToken token ){
    authenticationTokens.add( token.setUser(this) );
    return this;
}
```

When i call this method:

```
@Override @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
public User validateAuthenticationToken( final UserDTO userDTO ){
    .
    .
    .

    final AuthenticationToken dbAuthenticationToken = authenticationTokenBL.findByField( AuthenticationToken.Attributes.SELECTOR , userDTO.getAuthenticationToken().getSelector(), false );
    .
    .
    .
    final User user = dbAuthenticationToken.getUser();
    user.removeAuthenticationToken( dbAuthenticationToken ).addAuthenticationToken( newAuthenticationToken ) ;
    .
    .
    .
    return user;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The `authenticationToken` is added two times to the `authenticationTokens` list of the `user`.

I realized that when i set parent of the `authenticationToken`(`token.setUser(this)`), the Hibernate adds The `authenticationToken` to the list even if i remove `@Transactional`.

When i change the helper method to this:

```
public User addAuthenticationToken( final AuthenticationToken token ){
    authenticationTokens.add( token );
    token.setUser(this)
    return this;
}
```

The Hibernate dose not.

I tested it like this:

```
public User addAuthenticationToken( final AuthenticationToken token ){
    Global.printToConsole("User-addAuthenticationToken: ", "number of authenticationTokens: " + this.authenticationTokens.size() );
    authenticationTokens.add( token.setUser(this) );
    Global.printToConsole("User-addAuthenticationToken: ", "number of authenticationTokens: " + this.authenticationTokens.size() );
    return this;
}
```

And Like This:

```
public User addAuthenticationToken( final AuthenticationToken token ){
    Global.printToConsole("User-addAuthenticationToken: ", "number of authenticationTokens: " + this.authenticationTokens.size() );
    token.setUser(this);
    Global.printToConsole("User-addAuthenticationToken: ", "number of authenticationTokens: " + this.authenticationTokens.size() );
    authenticationTokens.add( token );
    Global.printToConsole("User-addAuthenticationToken: ", "number of authenticationTokens: " + this.authenticationTokens.size() );
    return this;
}
```

Can someone explain that?

Thanks in advance.

**I'm using:**

- Java Language: v20
- Hibernate: v6.1.7
- Apache Tomee Plus: v9.1.0

Comment: I don't follow your question or use case. You are adding a token to the authenticationTokens list yourself, is the token already in the list when you are maybe adding it a second time?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Chris. No, the list is empty just before adding.

Comment: Where exactly are you detecting there is a duplicate entry in the List? Try stepping through the code in a debugger to see exactly where it is added and show the setUser method.

Comment: @Chris, I detected that by printing to the console. I updated my question.

Comment: Is your setUser method also modifying the authenticationTokens list? Combined with your addAuthenticationToken logic, that would explain duplicate entries in the collection and why the order of the calls affects the outcome.

Comment: @Chris, No it's just a simple setter. `this.user = user;`;

Comment: @Chris, I also created new project just for testing; The result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was known issue [Hibernate inserts duplicates into @OneToMany collection](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6776). But This should have been fixed.

I tested another way:

```
public User addAuthenticationToken( final AuthenticationToken token ){
    Global.printToConsole("User-addAuthenticationToken: ", "number of authenticationTokens: " + this.authenticationTokens.size() );
    token.setUser(this);
    Global.printToConsole("User-addAuthenticationToken: ", "number of authenticationTokens: " + this.authenticationTokens.size() );
    authenticationTokens.add( token );
    Global.printToConsole("User-addAuthenticationToken: ", "number of authenticationTokens: " + this.authenticationTokens.size() );
    token.setUser(this);
    Global.printToConsole("User-addAuthenticationToken: ", "number of authenticationTokens: " + this.authenticationTokens.size() );        
    return this;
}
```

The result was interesting:

```
User-addAuthenticationToken: number of authenticationTokens: 0
User-addAuthenticationToken: number of authenticationTokens: 1
User-addAuthenticationToken: number of authenticationTokens: 2
User-addAuthenticationToken: number of authenticationTokens: 1
```

Comment: Maybe show the setUser method logic because I don’t see JPA/hibernate involved here at all.